# jplayer clicking play nothing happening

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, jplayer

I am currently working with jPlayer to add some sound clips to my website, however when I click play, nothing happens...the page just reloads as if I have clicked a link, below is my HTML and my javascript, and also the altered DOM.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $('.voice').click(function(e) {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setFile", $(this).attr('rel')).jPlayer("play");
                e.preventDefault();
                });
            },
            solution: "flash, html", // Flash with an HTML5 fallback.
            swfPath: "/media/js/jPlayer/",
            wmode: "window"
        });
});



   <li><a href="" rel="<?php echo base_url(); ?>media/uploads/audio/<?php echo $candidate_audio['url']; ?>" class="voice">Play Voice Over</a></li>
```

the flash holder

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer"></div>
```

altered on domReady too....

```
<div id="jquery_jplayer" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img id="jp_poster_0" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;">
    <object width="1" height="1" id="jp_flash_0" data="/media/js/jPlayer/Jplayer.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <param name="flashvars" value="jQuery=jQuery&amp;id=jquery_jplayer&amp;vol=0.8&amp;muted=false">
    <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
    <param name="wmode" value="window">
    </object>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I used jPlayer, but I think this line: `$(this).jPlayer("setFile"...` is the problem. Since you're doing that in a click-handler, `this` will probably point to the wrong element. I would try this:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
    ready: function (event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.voice').click(function(e) {
            $this.jPlayer("setFile", $(this).attr('rel')).jPlayer("play");
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    },
    solution: "flash, html", // Flash with an HTML5 fallback.
    swfPath: "/media/js/jPlayer/",
    wmode: "window"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how it's working for me.  Note the first line which assigns a click handler to block the default behavior of clicking a link...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('[class^="jp-"]').click(function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });

    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
       ready: function () {
           $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
               mp3: "/music/mySong.mp3"
            });
       },
       swfPath: "/jPlayer/js",
       supplied: "mp3",
       volume: 0.6
    });
});
```

In your case, you could try the following.  The `preventDefault()` should be the first item in the function...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $('.voice').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();  // <-- first item in this function
                $(this).jPlayer("setFile", $(this).attr('rel')).jPlayer("play");
            });
        },
        solution: "flash, html", // Flash with an HTML5 fallback.
        swfPath: "/media/js/jPlayer/",
        wmode: "window"
    });
});
```

Also note that in your original posting, you've either made a simple typo on SO or a programming error.  There is an extra set of closing brackets, `});` or you've misplaced/left out the initial `document.ready` line.

```
        $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer({
            ready: function (event) {
                $('.voice').click(function(e) {
                    $(this).jPlayer("setFile", $(this).attr('rel')).jPlayer("play");
                e.preventDefault();
                });
            },
            solution: "flash, html", // Flash with an HTML5 fallback.
            swfPath: "/media/js/jPlayer/",
            wmode: "window"
        }); 
});  // <--- remove extra closing brackets
```